Flutter iOS clipboard does not copy all the data from Whatsapp or Telegram chats
Context and Problem:
I am trying to let the user manually copy and paste chats from a chat app- say like WhatsApp to a Textfield in my flutter app. It works fine in android, but, in iOS, only one (of multiple selected and copied) chats are copied to the Textfield. When I try to paste in other native iOS apps or Notes app, it works fine. I tried printing the flutter Clipboard - in iOS, it only prints one random chat of multiple selected and copied chats. I suspect it is a clipboard problem with Flutter - that breaks in iOS.
What I tried doing:
Selected multiple Whatsapp Chats in macOS / iOS - tried the same in MacOS, ipad and iPhone. The below screeenshot is from macOS. But, the same behaviour exists across iOS as well.
Pasted the chat in the flutter text box and tried printing the clipboard.




void pasteFromClipboard() async {
  ClipboardData? clipboardData = await Clipboard.getData(Clipboard.kTextPlain);
  if (clipboardData != null) {
    String? completeText = clipboardData.text;
    print('Previous Paste from clipboard data: $completeText');
    completeText = (clipboardData.text ?? '').replaceAll(RegExp(r'[\u202A-\u202E\u00A0\u200B]'), ' ').trim();
    print('Formatted Paste from clipboard data: $completeText');
  }
}



Expected output
[29/08/24, 5:37:40 PM] +31 121548: Can you please let me know ho I can get the refund
[29/08/24, 6:49:02 PM] My Name: I can help with the refund. Can you please let me know the reason?
[29/08/24, 5:36:31 PM] +31 121548: Hi
Actual output:
Just one random line of the multiple chats copied.
"[29/08/24, 6:49:02 PM] My Name: I can help with the refund. Can you please let me know the reason?"
The same behavior happens for both physical and virtual devices.
